# Large ninepatch stretching

Tags: java, android, libgdx, nine-patch

The image below needs to be stretched just over the grey area vertically. The rest of the image should expand equally horizontally so it fills up the screen.

[image]

So I have setup the ninepatch as `0, 0, 158, 28` [(a, b, c, d)](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Ninepatches#defining-a-ninepatch-programmatically). And when I use this as a `Table` background this is the result.

[image]

It looks to me the image is "just" filling the screen and ignoring the ninepatch split completely.

My world size is 140 wide and 250 high atm. And the image is 733 wide. Could this be the problem? I never had issues with ninepatch on small images.

This is how I setup the image:

```
    winTable = new Table(skin);
    winTable.background("winpanel");
    winTable.setFillParent(true);

    stage.addActor(winTable);

//And this is how the image in the atlas is specified
winpanel
  rotate: false
  xy: 0, 298
  size: 733, 203
  split: 0, 0, 158, 28
  orig: 733, 203
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
```

I tried to play with the numbers to get a good result without success. I also tried to create a `NinePatch` manually and use that in a `Image` but I am getting the same result. Now I'm wondering if it's even possible to do what I want and maybe I need to split the banner from the rest of the image. But then the two images should line up perfectly.

Comment: Have you tried texture packer for this? I personally use it in games and works fine.

Comment: @Kush Yes, I'm always packing all my textures. But afaik there is no option to make a ninepatch or `split` in that app so as you can see I add the `split` manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the method I use for ninepatches and it works for me. I don't have the "split" line in my atlas, so you may not need to use it with this.

```
TextureRegion region = skin.getRegion("winpanel");
NinePatch patch = new NinePatch(region, 0, 0, 158, 28);
NinePatchDrawable drawable = new NinePatchDrawable(patch);      
winTable.setBackground(drawable);
```

***EDIT:*** I just noticed you mentioned that your world size is 140 wide and the image is 733 wide...this is very likely your problem because it is squeezing the width of the image to fit your table. Open the image in a photo editor and scale the image so that the width exactly same as the width that you want it to appear in your game. Then try the ninepatch with new values for your new images size and see if it works.

Comment: I already tried that and it yields the exact same result. It's exactly the same as specifying the split and using the atlas lookup to set a table background.

Comment: Even if that would solve the problem I would not want that. The image would become blurry. Let's say I would use world units of 16x9 then I could only use an image of 16x9 that would get stretched all the way over many pixels. World units should have no relation to pixel density.

Comment: Unfortunately there's really no way around that without scaling. If the width of the image has to be the same size as your screen then you'll have to scale it to fit different resolution widths. There are tricks you can do like include multiple images for different resolutions, or you can include a single high-resolution image and then scale it down within the program. In the project I'm working on now, I actually draw the graphics using the Pixmap draw methods to the exact size of the device on the first run to avoid any scaling/blurriness, but my graphics are much simpler than your image.

Comment: One more idea...can you use a different image which is flat on the top instead of arched? Then you could ninepatch it to stretch it both vertically and horizontally to fill out the screen in all directions without having to scale it.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but replacing artwork to work with the code is not a path I'd like to take. I will try to cut it up and fix it in another way. Since I'm drawing this on a stage on top of my actual game that needs the 140x250 for gameplay purpose I will fiddle around with the stage width to get it right.

Comment: I guess your answer is correct, just not what I wanted to hear. Eveywhere people are shouting to use world units instead of pixels and now I have to change everything into pixels again or use world units that are at least larger then my images. I felt very comfortable with using 1 world unit as a single tile for example.

Comment: I'm not sure how to handle game units I've only ever worked in pixels, I'm not a game developer and I only do UI based apps so working in pixels is easiest for me. If you want to give the scaling thing a try, this article covers mipmaps which generates different sized images for different resolutions. http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1403